# How to restrict only one parameter in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, salt-stack

I have the below pipeline script with string parameters. The Target parameter will fail if multiple comma separated inputs (target1, target2) are provided in Jenkins. How can I restrict the Jenkins pipeline to accept just one parameter (target) as parameter and not multiple comma separated values.

```
properties([
  parameters([
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'ID'),
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'Target')
  ])
])
```

Comment: you could just check the parameters as a first stage/step and throw an exception.

Comment: hakamairi, thanks. Any hint on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do in the first stage/step

```
if ((params.Target.split(',')).size() > 1) {
    error("Build failed because of this and that..")
}
```